# VNC Server running on Linux machine to access all the terminals open on the Linux

Tags: linux, vncserver

I have a Linux Ubuntu(11.10) box at work, on which I open 4 terminals and execute different processes(my code). I run vncserver on this Linux box, so as to access it remotely.

When I login to my office Windows PC using vpn, I would like to connect to this office Linux desktop using VNC Client and be able to see all the Linxu desktop which had my 4 open terminals executing the programs.

How to use VNC to view Desktop of Linux PC and all the terminals associated to that which I opened to execute my programs?

Comment: all of that seems reasonable and easy to accomplish. what problems are you having?

Comment: @Frank Thomas I did not see my terminals when I connected to the VNC server. It showed a desktop with a new terminal open in it.

Comment: It should work as you suggest. what vnc client are you using, and are you being promted to login to ubuntu (not to teh vnc server, but to ubuntu itself) when you connect to VNC?

Comment: VNC Viewer ver 5.0.6 on windows. I am asked to login to the VNC server, where I enter my VNC password i configured on vnc server.

Comment: Could you let know steps involved to see if i am doing anything wrong?

Comment: vpn into your work network. then you can either connect to your windows station over RDP, and from there VNC to the linux box, or you can just connect to the linux box via vnc from your host. either way, you may be prompted to login to vnc's service, and you desktop should be shown, pretty much exactly as if you were at it physically. here is the ubuntu doc on vnc: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers